# How to apply focusout or blur event on a section as a whole?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

we have implemented a functionality that after clicking on a button, a section appears having input and search button and when the complete section blurs when navigated using tab key, then the original button comes back. We have added onfocusout event to capture child element blur event, but it is getting triggering separately for each element i.e. when user clicks on input, then press tab key, instead of going to button, it hides the section. We want when the complete div goes out of focus then it gets hidden. Is there a way to achieve this? Also, as the code needs to be written in Angular, so won't we able to use jQuery if there might be some solution using it.

```js
function showButton() {
  var x = document.getElementById("searchWithButton");
  x.classList.add("display-none");
  
  var y = document.getElementById("search");
  y.classList.remove("display-none");
}

function showSearchDiv() {
  var x = document.getElementById("searchWithButton");
  x.classList.remove("display-none");
  
  var y = document.getElementById("search");
  y.classList.add("display-none");
  
  var z = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  z.focus();
}
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 
 .display-none {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="searchWithButton" onfocusout="showButton()" class="red-border display-none">
  <input id="searchInput" type="text">
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
<button id="search" onclick="showSearchDiv()">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the desired behavior to hide the `searchWithButton`? May I suggest any of the following: a click outside, pressing [escape]. Or focusing another element using [tab] (a little patchy)

```js
var x = document.getElementById("searchWithButton");
var y = document.getElementById("search");
var z = document.getElementById("searchInput");

function showButton() {
  x.classList.add("display-none");
  y.classList.remove("display-none");
}

function showSearchDiv() {
  x.classList.remove("display-none");
  y.classList.add("display-none");
  z.focus();
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
  if (ev.keyCode==27) {
    showButton();
  }
})

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(ev) {
  if (!ev.target.closest("#searchWithButton")) {
    showButton()
  }
})

document.querySelectorAll(".get-focus").forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('focus', showButton)
})
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
before: <input type="text" name="before" class="get-focus">
<br><br>

<div id="searchWithButton" class="red-border display-none">
  <input id="searchInput" type="text">
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
<button id="search" onclick="showSearchDiv()">Search</button>

<br><br> after: <input type="text" name="after" class="get-focus">
```